# Why is gmail client (via Chrome and Android app) still strip <style> tag from HTML email?

Tags: gmail, media-queries, html-email

I recently reviewed the [Pluralsight course on HTML email](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/responsive-html-email-design/table-of-contents) and then made a sample for myself. I tested it through Mailchimp and the Mailchimp test environment renders it as expected for both mobile and desktop, but when I sent a test email to myself, both gmail clients that I use (Gmail app through Chrome on desktop and Android app on mobile) appeared to strip the style and link tags, in particular stripping the media screen size queries and associated classes, as well as font imports.

[This article](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design) claims that gmail clients are now accepting  tags, at least on most platforms, including the two I am testing. However, as noted the @media and @import queries are not working. (1) Is there something obviously wrong with my code?, or (2) is this an issue with Mailchimp?

HTML email code,  and part of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Happy Holidays!</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin|Libre+Baskerville|Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">

    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES ------------------- */

  #outlook a {
    padding: 0; /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
  } 

  .ReadMsgBody {
    width: 100%; /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
  } 

  .ExternalClass {
    width:100%; /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
  }

  .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
    line-height: 100%; /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
  }

  body, table, td, a { /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }

  table, td { /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-rspace:0pt;
  }

  img { /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  }

  /* RESET STYLES --------------------------- */

  body { 
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  img { 
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  /* iOS BLUE LINKS */

  .apple-links a { 
    color: #A50001;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  /* FONTS */
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin|Libre+Baskerville|Pacifico');

  /* MOBILE STYLES ------------------------ */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    td[class="logo"] img {
      margin: 0 auto !important;
    }

    table[class="wrapper"] {
      width: 100% !important;
    } 

    td[class="mobile-image-pad"] {
      padding: 0 10px 0 10px !important;
    }

    td[class="mobile-title-pad"] {
      padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px !important;
    }

    td[class="mobile-text-pad"] {
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
    }

    td[class="mobile-column-right"] {
      padding-top: 20px !important;
    }

    img[class="fluid-image"] {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
    }

    td[class="hide"] {
      display: none !important;
    } 

    td[class="mobile-button"] {
      padding: 12px 60px 12px 60px !important;
    }

    td[class="mobile-button"] a {
      font-size: 24px !important;
    }
  }


  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" >

  <!-- CONTAINER TABLE (HEADER) -->
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style=" table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#339969" style="padding: 0 0 0 0;">

        <!-- HIDDEN PREHEADER -->
        <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color:#333333; line-height: 1px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all;">
          Preheader inbox text
        </div>
        <!-- WRAPPER TABLE -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="wrapper">
          <!-- HEADER -->
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" background="img/url" alt="Bappy Bolidays!" width="100%" height="100" style="background-size:contain;">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- CONTAINER TABLE (HERO) -->
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#C3D79C" style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0;">
        <!-- WRAPPER TABLE -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="wrapper">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <!-- TWO COLUMNS -->
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="64%" align="left" class="wrapper">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="mobile-image-pad">
                                <img src="img/url" alt="Two Beautiful Peeps" width="384" height="288" border="0" style="display: block; image-orientation: from-image; color: #A50001; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; background-color: #339969; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;" class="fluid-image" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="30%" align="right" class="wrapper">
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="middle" height="100%">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="color: #A50001; font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 32px; line-height: 38px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);" class="mobile-title-pad">
                                Title
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="color: #339969; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px;" class="mobile-title-pad">
                                from
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="color: #A50001; font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 32px; line-height: 38px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);" class="mobile-title-pad">
                                Title
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;">
                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#339969" style="padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);" class="mobile-button">
                                      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08bLSIWGoSg#t=00m06s" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">let's go champ &rarr;</a>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>  
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- CONTAINER TABLE (VIGNETTES) -->
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff2f9" style="padding: 40px 0 40px 0;">
        <!-- WRAPPER TABLE -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="wrapper">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <!-- TWO COLUMNS (ROW 1) -->
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="47%" align="left" class="wrapper">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="mobile-image-pad">
                                <a href="album/location" target="_blank">
                                  <img src="img/url" alt="Kapanda" width="280" height="218" border="0" style="display: block; padding: 0; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; background-color: #589263; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;" class="fluid-image" />
                                </a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0; color: #A50001; font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; line-height: 22px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);" class="mobile-title-pad">
                                Title
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; color: #666666; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 18px; line-height: 22px;" class="mobile-text-pad">
                                <a href="album/location" target="_blank" style="color: #589263; text-decoration: none;">description</a> more description! 
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="47%" align="right" class="wrapper">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="mobile-column-right">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="mobile-image-pad">
                                <a href="album/location" target="_blank">
                                  <img src="url/img" alt="Hawaii Sunset" width="280" height="218" border="0" style="display: block; padding: 0; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; background-color: #589263; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;" class="fluid-image" />
                                </a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0; color: #339969; font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; line-height: 22px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);" class="mobile-title-pad">
                              Title
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; color: #666666; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 18px; line-height: 22px;" class="mobile-text-pad">
                                <a href="album/lcoation" target="_blank" style="color: #A50001; text-decoration: none;">Description</a> More description.
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Gmail generally doesn't support web-fonts](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts)**. If you have a web font installed on your own computer, you’ll be able to see it in Gmail, but that's it.

---

Gmail supports @media queries **almost everywhere, but not *everywhere***. The [Litmus article you referenced](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design) contains a support table of Gmail products and their @media query support.

There's little telling which product MailChimp Or Litmus are using to generate their previews, so it could look fine on their end and break in your account... with no error on either end.

You said that you checked using Android app on mobile, and that seems like one of the Gmail products that doesn't support media queries ↓ ↓ ↓

[image]

---

This is pure conjecture, but from what I understand Google is done rolling out this change. So those red x's might remain unsupported for some time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also saw that table, but the clients tested are "Desktop webmail" and "Gmail Android app (Gmail account)".

Comment: @Kwhitejr I missed the bit about web-fonts and updated my answer above. TL;DR: Gmail doesn't support web fonts. /// I tested your email and confirm that it's not responsive in Gmail (iOS), but can send responsive emails to that same email address. I believe there is an error somewhere in your code. **Sorry! I know this doesn't help much**, as I don't have time to debug it myself.

Comment: No worries! I can live without web-fonts, but need to work out why the mobile classes aren't being triggered. Thanks for convincing me I'm not crazy :D

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does support style blocks, but doesn't support selectors in CSS. Remove the selectors and your CSS will work. For example, change:

td[class="mobile-text-pad"]

to:

td.mobile-text-pad

And it should work.